# Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?

Tags: java, url, http-headers

I am accessing web pages through java as follows:

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
```

But in some cases, a url redirects to another url. So I want to know the url to which the previous url redirected.

Below are the header fields that I got as a response:

```
null-->[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Cache-control-->[public,max-age=3600]
last-modified-->[Sat, 17 Apr 2010 13:45:35 GMT]
Transfer-Encoding-->[chunked]
Date-->[Sat, 17 Apr 2010 13:45:35 GMT]
Vary-->[Accept-Encoding]
Expires-->[Sat, 17 Apr 2010 14:45:35 GMT]
Set-Cookie-->[cl_def_hp=copenhagen; domain=.craigslist.org; path=/; expires=Sun, 17     Apr 2011 13:45:35 GMT, cl_def_lang=en; domain=.craigslist.org; path=/; expires=Sun, 17 Apr 2011 13:45:35 GMT]
Connection-->[close]
Content-Type-->[text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;]
Server-->[Apache]
```

So at present, I am constructing the redirected url from the value of the `Set-Cookie` header field. In the above case, the redirected url is `copenhagen.craigslist.org`

Is there any standard way through which I can determine which url the particular url is going to redirect.

I know that when a url redirects to other url, the server sends an intermediate response containing a `Location` header field that tells the redirected url but I am not receiving that intermediate response through the `url.openConnection();` method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to cast the `URLConnection` to `HttpURLConnection` and instruct it to **not** follow the redirects by setting [`HttpURLConnection#setInstanceFollowRedirects()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) to `false`. You can also set it globally by [`HttpURLConnection#setFollowRedirects()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29).

You only need to handle redirects yourself then. Check the response code by [`HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29), grab the `Location` header by [`URLConnection#getHeaderField()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) and then fire a new HTTP request on it.

Comment: what's the diff. between `setInstanceFollowRedirects()` and `setFollowRedirects` methods. I checked the API but couldn't understand the diff. between both.

Comment: Yes. I also explicitly said, "..you can set it *globally* by..". Follow the links to API docs. They describe precisely what the methods do.

Comment: Could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526861/java-applet-java-util-missingresourceexception

Comment: @BalusC can you please share some code to manually handle redirects

Answer (score 101):

Simply call getUrl() on URLConnection instance after calling getInputStream():

```
URLConnection con = new URL( url ).openConnection();
System.out.println( "orignal url: " + con.getURL() );
con.connect();
System.out.println( "connected url: " + con.getURL() );
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
System.out.println( "redirected url: " + con.getURL() );
is.close();
```

If you need to know whether the redirection happened before actually getting it's contents, here is the sample code:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL( url ).openConnection());
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
con.connect();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println( responseCode );
String location = con.getHeaderField( "Location" );
System.out.println( location );
```

Comment: Please follow the formatting instructions in the sidebar when you compose/edit your posts, rather than trying to format with HTML tags. The result is much prettier.

Comment: Great answer, able to copy and paste first section of code and it worked right away.

Comment: Great answer, if first section fails (redirected url = original url), then second section solves the problem.

Comment: `con.getURL` doesn't return a correct URL for me when there's a redirect to a "https" address (e.g. http://www.google.com), no matter if it is 301 or 302 (tried both)

Comment: Thank you!! It helps me much!

Answer (score 15):

```
public static URL getFinalURL(URL url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");
        con.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        con.addRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.google.com/");
        con.connect();
        //con.getInputStream();
        int resCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER
                || resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                || resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
            String Location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
            if (Location.startsWith("/")) {
                Location = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + Location;
            }
            return getFinalURL(new URL(Location));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return url;
}
```

To get "**User-Agent**" and "**Referer**" by yourself, just go to developer mode of one of your installed browser (E.g. press F12 on Google Chrome). Then go to tab 'Network' and then click on one of the requests. You should see it's details. Just press 'Headers' sub tab (the image below)
[image: request details]

Comment: What is the "crawl" object?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `HttpURLConnection` class [API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), especially `setInstanceFollowRedirects()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually suggest using a solid open-source library as an http client.  If you take a look at [http client](http://hc.apache.org/) by ASF you'll find life a lot easier.  It is an easy-to-use,scalable and robust client for http.

Comment: Please post as well how you would answer this particular question when using HttpClient.

Answer (score -7):

@balusC I did as you wrote . In my case , I've added cookie information to be able to reuse the session .

```
   // get the cookie if need
    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

    // open the new connnection again
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?