# Get redirect from httprequest in Java

Tags: java, url, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url)

Hi all,

Let's say I want to know which Wikipedia page corresponds to this url:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ireland

If I navigate it with a browser, I can see that it's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ireland.
is there a way to get the real url from a Java application?

Mulone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an HttpURLConnection you can use *setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean)* to prevent the connection to follow the redirect. If the response code is in the 300s, you can get the *Location* header which will have the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning URL redirect off in your browser - the exact configuration depends on your installed one for this.

[edit] If you want to do in Java - you can turn off automated HTTP redirects via getFollowRedirects() option.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I believe the OP wants to do this in a Java application, not in a web browser.

Comment: in fact, I don't want to disable url redirection, but the opposite: I want to follow the redirection and get the final url in my Java app.