# java Desktop browse: how to get the current URL?

Tags: java, authentication, browser, external, vk

I am trying to implement authentication of my standalone java application at VKontakte - Russian social network.

I want to avoid requesting a password from the user, so my method is like this:

1. open default browser with a special generated URL
2. in the opened page user clicks Accept button
3. browser gets redirected to a special URL from where I can extract access_token which is supposed to be used for any other further request.

But the problem is that I do not know how to get that new URL from the browser.
The code I am using is

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI("some URL here");
                desktop.browse(uri);
```

Comment: probably you can advice some other class instead of Desktop to get that kind of functionality.

Comment: When i execute it with my program the browser comes up over my program automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Desktop.browse(). You are initializing an instance of a program(browser) that java has no access to. Java only passed the URL you provided.

(Theoretically it would be possible, if i.e. Desktop.browse() would start a custom made Browser that you can communicate with via Java API)

Comment: any idea how to make this without Desktop.browse()?

Comment: Do you need the user to click Accept in the browser? If it's a java applet you are developing how about you click it automatically?

Comment: Yes, without his click, redirect would not happen

Comment: IF the Accept button has lots of JS behind it, you could use JUnit to simulate the browser. JUnit is used by software engineers to test their solutions, but I used it successfully to access websites with lots of JS. The browser won't be displayed and you could automate the clicking. From there you can obtain the redirect URL.

Comment: IF however the Accept button is simply another URL i suggest using URLConnection and finding its redirect value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url

Comment: If the user is not logged in, then he would need to input the password in the browser and clicking won't be automated.

Comment: Can't you use the VKontakte API? Do they provide such a thing at all?

Comment: There are 3 options:
1) connect with email and pass: not recommended and outdated
2) webview in java application. Probably application can intercept email and password input by the user.
3) this approach