# How to bck in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Here i am displaying URL in BrowserActivity.After opening site when i pressed back i should go back But here reloading. Because with my url another url opening.My Url is correct only. Just advice me with one back press how i return to my activity.If i press 2 times back button then its working properly (means going to previous activity).I posted my code below. Try with that url only please..

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myWebLink.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
    myWebLink.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.abcd.com"));
    startActivity(myWebLink);}});
```

Comment: Hi.You are asking for back button click?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
  {
    switch(keyCode)
    {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        if(myWebLink.canGoBack() == true)
        {
          myWebLink.goBack();
        }
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: And I want to show browser thats why iam using Intent.otherwise i can use webview

Comment: how i can open browser in webview? once try with my url. then you will understand  the problem . plz...

Comment: If you want to open in browser, you can use like this..        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: Link should  open in browser? or link should open in webview?@user1897519

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23948/discussion-between-ramji-and-user1897519)

Comment: Instead of "google.com" use this link "http://www.bigticketshop.co.uk/clickout.aspx?did=326177&mid=101&d=21-04-2013&e=A Gala for St George&po=2". My requirement link should open in browser

Answer (score 0):

Android activities are stored in the activity stack. Going back to a previous activity could mean two things.

1. You opened the new activity from another activity with **startActivityForResult**. In that case you can just call the **finishActivity()** function from your code and it'll take you back to the previous activity.
2. Keep track of the activity stack. Whenever you start a new activity with an intent you can specify an intent flag like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP. You can use this to shuffle between the activities in your application. Haven't used them much though. Have a look at the flags here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

The website which you are accessing is :

```
http://www.bigticketshop.co.uk/clickout.aspx?did=326177&mid=101&d=21-04-2013&e=A Gala for St George&po=2
```

which is redirecting to :

```
http://www.seatwave.com/a-gala-for-st-george-tickets/royal-albert-hall-tickets/21-april-2013/perf/633910?affid=0316
```

So when you are pressing back button it is going back to your old website which is again redirecting to the new one ,hence It goes in a loop.

Directly try new web site it is working fine:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myWebLink.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
    myWebLink.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.seatwave.com/a-gala-for-st-george-tickets/royal-albert-hall-tickets/21-april-2013/perf/633910?affid=0316"));
    startActivity(myWebLink);}});
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my issue. but i cant get that new site url. From webservice i will get so many urls.By clicking list item iam displaying this url. If it is only one url then i can use second one. but i have hundreds of urls. All redirect to another url

Comment: In this case just catch the redirected URL and put that in the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url . This link will help you catching the redirecting URL.