# Check if website exists

Tags: java, web

I'm trying to make a is-website-down utility with java, but I have some problems.

Is there a way to check if a website exists? I tried this to see if a website is down:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("code: " + code);
```

It goes through `IOException` for `Connection refused: connect` when i.e. i try to connect to localhost while there is no active http server listening (the site is down).

I thought it would happen the same thing with some site that actually doesn't exist i.e.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.sdfasfjkhaslfjkhaslkdjfhasldkjf.it");
```

But i receive a HTTP Status code 200 because my ISP automatically redirects me to a random advertisement page if the site i'm searching for doesn't exist.

So, if a site is down, my program says "Well, your website is down", but if the site doesn't exist my program says "Oh, your website is up and running!", and that's not really good.

Is there a way to check if a website exists?

Comment: Wow, what a bad ISP.

Comment: @eboix Yeah. Unfortunately, i think every italian ISP works like this

Comment: If your ISP redirects you like this, you can also assume it is not available.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes. The fact is that every different ISP handles this situation in a different way, so i need a general one that can work with every ISP

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you might not have the port numbers in local host e.g. http://localhost:8080/

Comment: @Dan no, it says that it's down even with `localhost:80` and `localhost:8080`

Comment: They're returning a 200 for a redirect? Urg. Ideally they shouldn't fore this behaviour on you, but they could at least do a 301 status code! :(

Comment: Well for a quick sanity check, I started up my jetty and ran your code on one of my local pages.  It work and got back 200.

Comment: Normally ISPs use Javascript to do the redirect, not a 301/302.

Comment: @StevenVondruska if my isp used JS to do the redirect it wouldn't just redirect, as a URLConnection doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: @Harlandraka good point. Didn't think about that. But some ISPs do use Javascript, so if this application is going to be released on a larger scale, something you need to think about as well.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments about the ISP DNS poisoning. Your ISP is giving/leasing you a DNS server they are in control over that catches all `NXDOMAIN` responses and return a poisoned result to a server they control.

I would do a DNS check for an A record with something like [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or some other publically known valid DNS server before you do the HTTP check. Google Public DNS does return `NXDOMAIN` when the domain is invalid. In Java, you may need to use something like [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) to get direct access to the DNS records you need.

In the end, do two checks, one for a valid DNS record against a known good source, then another one to see if HTTP is alive.

Comment: How can i check google DNSes without setting them? I can't ask the application user to change his DNS settings, is there a way to "ask" them if a website is resolved without setting them as default DNSes?

Comment: You wouldn't change the end user's DNS servers. You'd set the DNS server in your application to do the lookup. If you open a command prompt/terminal session type `nslookup kjfksadljfksl.com` then type `nslookup kjfksadljfksl.com 8.8.8.8`. You're telling `nslookup` to do the lookup against Google, and not against your ISP's DNS servers. You would do a similar thing in your code.

Comment: `nslookup kjfksadljfksl.com 8.8.8.8` means i have to execute terminal commands from my java application, it would be better if i don't... I'll try dnsjava, maybe it solves all my problems!

Answer (score 1):

Just found [Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url) which suggests setting httpConnection.setFollowRedirects(false) - that could help if they're doing actual redirects. If they're not redirecting but are just serving up their own content not sure there' much to be done except detect if the content is what you expected or if it's advertising.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add :

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
// note : or
//        httpConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

and control :

```
(httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
```