# How can I retrieve the multiple URLs provided in the body of an HTTP response with code 300?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-redirect

**I have the following piece of Java code:**

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","");
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

When the response-code is 300, how can I extract the URLs that are provided within the response body?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url)

Comment: No duplicate. For code=300, I cannot "grab the Location header" (as the post you provide suggests), because there is no Location header in that kind of response.