# How do i get Instagram Code for Oauth authorisation?

Tags: java, oauth, instagram

I am making desktop app in java for instagram right now and i don't know how to get code from callback url. My app is desktop so my REDIRECT-URI is http://instagram.com. So in my app i send a request to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code and get redirected to instagram.com?code=CODE. And also forgot to mention, I get a code once by my hands a i gave all permissions. So now then i make request i redirected straightly to URL with code.
 How do i get code from callback uri in program in java? This is my code:

```
static void GetCode()
{
    try {
        String url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + ClientId + "&redirect_uri=" + BackUri + "&response_type=code&scope=likes+comments+relationships";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("GET CODE ERROR->"+e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to double check, have you registered with instagram as a developer? http://instagram.com/developer/register/

Comment: Yes, of course. And also forgot to mention, I get a code once by my hands a i gave all permissions. So now then i make request i redirected straightly to URL with code.

Comment: Can you share the result? I am in the same situation and I can't find the way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `REDIRECT_URI` to `http://localhost`. So the actual 'redirection' code should be done on your side. And you can parse value of argument `code`. Also  look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url). This will help you to grab URI with the code.

Comment: you need a server for this?

Comment: No. `HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode()`  and  _Location_ header from `URLConnection#getHeaderField()` are enough.