# Using the userID to get a large profile picture Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little unsure how to retrieve a large profile picture from facebook current when I use the picture ID. I am loading this URL into my imageview.

http://graph.facebook.com/1454465268197338/picture?type=large

But it doesn't load, when I enter this though it works.

[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/11014854_1403982213245644_5725357301610737602_n.jpg?oh=9d95140ca58c8e13a950e14f63018ff4&oe=55F8A88F&**gda**=1442905098_49d2c7ec583d417722e02a10206c0fb6](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/11014854_1403982213245644_5725357301610737602_n.jpg?oh=9d95140ca58c8e13a950e14f63018ff4&oe=55F8A88F&__gda__=1442905098_49d2c7ec583d417722e02a10206c0fb6)

What I put above is the REDIRECTED URL after I put in the first. The problem is I cannot produce that with the userID I am given because I am using this.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
        Event ci = contactList.get(i);
        contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);

        TinyDB userinfo =new TinyDB(context);

        String user_id = userinfo.getString("id");
        profile_pic_url ="http://graph.facebook.com/"+user_id+"/picture?type=large";

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(profile_pic_url)
                .resize(225, 225)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(contactViewHolder.vProfilePic);

    }
```

Pay attention to the profile_pic_url.

So ultimately, how can I get the redirected url (because I know that works)?

OR

how can I get a LARGE facebook profile picture url from the user because keep in mind the facebook android id because what I get from this:

```
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,picture,friends");
```

IS REALLY SMALL.

I tried using

[Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

No luck unfortunately,

help is appreciated.

TYTY

Comment: pass height and width in url

Comment: i donot know in java but

Comment: URL like this

 String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+_id+"/picture?height=120
                    &width=120";

Comment: use this link and there is any get or post if  then use get

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/1454465268197338/picture?height=120&width=120

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,picture.type(large),friends");
```

– that should get you the large version of the profile picture.

(This makes use of [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion) syntax to specify which data you want more precisely.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get good large photo with minimym width of 1000 pic, for example, and height given from aspect ratio, using next code:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {  
                                    String profileImg = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "/picture?type=large&width=1000";                                     
                                }
                            });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString(AuthConstants.FIELDS,
                            AuthConstants.ID + "," +
                                    AuthConstants.BIRTHDAY + "," +
                                    AuthConstants.FIRST_NAME + "," +
                                    AuthConstants.LAST_NAME + "," +
                                    AuthConstants.GENDER);

                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }
```

Where

```
public static final String FIELDS = "fields";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
public static final String FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
public static final String GENDER = "gender";
public static final String LAST_NAME = "last_name";
```