# How to get new URL when the input URL changes?

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

Consider this URL `http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jpdc.1997.1383`. When I put it in the browser address bar and press enter, the URL will change into `http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0743731597913836`. Using Java, how can I get the second URL address?

Comment: do you want to detect the url redirection after URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to find the redirected url of a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URLConnection con = new URL( url ).openConnection();
System.out.println( "orignal url: " + con.getURL() );
con.connect();
System.out.println( "connected url: " + con.getURL() );
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
System.out.println( "redirected url: " + con.getURL() );
is.close();
```

Comment: what is the point of `InputStream is = con.getInputStream();`? you even did not use it. and you dont have to. Just write `con.getInputStream();`

Comment: You are kind a interacting with the source ( this way you are knowing the precise end point ). So if it is redicted, con.getURL() will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `getUrl()` on `URLConnection` instance after calling `getInputStream()`